# swift 4 - difference between Alamofire and Retrofit (Post @Body Class)

Tags: swift, alamofire

i sent my android class by "retrofit library" (like alamofire) and server can parse it success
but when i use "alamofire", server cant found my parameters and i get nil

i think it's because i sent Body in java and in swift i send parameters and it is not like a body

android example

class:

```
public class Car implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("strMobileNumber") //<--- serialize
private String strMobileNumber= "";
@SerializedName("strOfficialIMEI")
private String strOfficialIMEI= "";
// ... geter and setter...
```

retrofit end point:

```
@POST("/Rest/Login") // <== post
Call<Car> getLogin(@Body Car car); //// **<=== @BODY**
```

request:

```
private void postRequest(Car car) {
    ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    Call<Car> call = apiService.getLogin(car);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Car>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Car> call, Response<Car> response) {
            stopLoading();
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                switch (response.body().getResult()) {
                    case "1":
                        //do somrthing
                        break;
                    case "0":
                        //do somrthing
                        break;
                    default:
                        //do somrthing
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                //do somrthing
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Car> call, Throwable t) {
           //do somrthing
        }
    });
}
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------

---

i try this for alamofire but server can not parse my parameters:

my class:

```
class User: Codable {
    private var strMobileNumber: String
    private var strOfficialIMEI : String

    init(strMobileNumber: String, strOfficialIMEI: String) {
       self.strMobileNumber = strMobileNumber
       self.strOfficialIMEI = strOfficialIMEI
    }

    func toParams () -> [String : Any] {
        return [
            "strMobileNumber" : self.strMobileNumber as Any,
            "strOfficialIMEI" : self.strOfficialIMEI as Any
        ]
    }
}
```

my request:

```
Alamofire.request(Values.connection.url("Login") , method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: ["Content-Type":"applocation/json"]).responseJSON { (response) in
       switch response.result {
       case .success(let json):
           let dict = json as? [String: Any]
           print(dict!["<KEY>"])
           break
       case .failure(let error):
           print(error)
           break
       }
   }
```

swift 4.2
alamofire 4.7

Comment: Do `let request = Alamofire.request(..); print("request: \(request)"); `request.responseJSON{...}` then you should able to see what's wrong. Where are put your params: Body, URLs, header, and how they are formatted too (JSON encoding, etc.)

Comment: How is your param variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 changes you need to do in your API call:

- Change encoding method to `JSONEncoding.default`
- Change headers value to `["Content-Type":"application/json"]`

URLEncoding.default is used when we pass data in URL itself. If we want to pass data in body, we should use `JSONEncoding.default`

Also there is a spelling mistake in header's content-type.

Answer (score 2):

i think Alamofire parameter encoding method Not right you may need insted of `URLEncoding.default` to use `JSONEncoding.default`

Comment: can you print the whole response not 
   let dict = json as? [String: Any]
   print(dict!["<KEY>"])